# Complex constraints in SciPy minimize

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, shapely, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to set up a few constraints for my minimization problem which looks as below:
`result = minimize(objective_func, initial_guess, constraints=all_constraints)`
where the `initial_guess = [0, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 8, 5, 10, 5, 15, 5, 17, 4, 20, 3]` is a polyline which consists of the following points (0,0), (5,0), (8,0) ... (17, 4), (20, 3).
How can I add into **all_constraints** a constraint that requires that all points are within a given shapely polygon **inclusion_polygon** ?

This is the current constraint that I have implemented with respect to the inclusion of the points from the given polyline:

```
def line_within_con(polyline):
    polyline = [(polyline[i], polyline[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(polyline) - 1, 2)]
    line_string = LineString(polyline)
    if not line_string.within(inclusion_polygon):
        return (-1) * line_string.distance(inclusion_polygon)
    else:
        return line_string.distance(inclusion_polygon)
```

and **all_constraints** looks as below:

```
all_constraints = [..., {'type': 'ineq', 'fun':line_within_con}, ....]
```

This constraint aims to penalize the case where the polyline is not included within the polygon by the distance to the polygon. Am I doing something wrong with the implementation of this constraint, as the minimization problem seems to totally ignore this constraint. How can I improve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I expect the current constraint, as it's defined, to behave very poorly. Instead, you should construct a linear constraint with rows for every single facet of the inclusion polygon, where every facet performs a projection of the given polyline vertex onto a facet tangent. Return from the constraint a vector of all of these projections. I cannot show you how to do this unless you include reproducible code.